# Issues with NaN output for a c++ complex function

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I have a c++ function for an RRC filter. The code. compiles and runs smoothly, but it gives a NaN output for a specified complex function.
The code in question is:

```
std::complex<float> rrc_output(const std::vector<std::complex<float>>& ht,
                               const std::deque<std::complex<float>>& rrc_sample_buffer){

    std::complex<float> yt = 0.;

    for (int n = 0; n < ht.size(); n++)
        yt += ht[n]*rrc_sample_buffer[n]; 

    return yt;
}
```

For more. clarity, the `rrc _sample_buffer` takes in 2-tuple inputs, (x,y) from a text file, and the `ht` is defined by the following formulae with conditions attached:

```
for (int i = 1; i< ht.size()+1; i++){
        if (t == 0){
            ht[i] = Rs*(1+(beta*((4/pi)-1)));
        }
        else if ( t == (Ts/(4*beta)) || t == -(Ts/(4*beta))){
            ht[i] = (beta/Ts*sqrt(2))*((1+(2/pi))*sin(pi/(4*beta))+(1-(2/pi))*cos(pi/(4*beta)));
        }
        else{
            ht[i] = (Rs*(sin(pi*t*Rs*(1-beta))+(4*beta*t*Rs*cos(pi*t*Rs*(1-beta)))))/(pi*t*Rs*(1-pow((4*beta*t*Rs),2)));
        }
```

where the length of `ht` and `rrc_sample_buffer` are:

```
vector<complex<float>> ht(sps, 0); 
std::deque<complex<float>> rrc_sample_buffer(ht.size(), 0.);
```

Any ideas on how I can get this fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of `ht` and `rrc_sample_buffer`? Most likely one of them contains a `nan` value somewhere.

Comment: Are `ht` and `rrc_sample_buffer` of the same length?

Comment: @DeGo. Yes, the both of them are of the same length.

Comment: @Brian. `rrc_sample_buffer` contains a bunch of 2-Tuple inputs from a text file and `ht` is defined by a formula with conditions attache to them.

Comment: I would step through the `for()` loop with a debugger and inspecting the values of `ht[n]` and `rrc_sample_buffer[n]`. Failing that, try placing an `if()` in the `for()` loop which tests `ht[n]` and `rrc_sample_buffer[n]` for `NaN` values, and print out a message if one occurs.

Comment: there's no point calling `sqrt(2)` repeatedly in a loop. Store it in a constant instead